# What is the preferred method for using OR statement within query string?

Tags: django, api, query-string, tastypie, url-parsing

I am writing an API with django-tastypie. The API using query string for filtering objects.

For example: If I want to find customers which has 'foo' in first_name, I am giving this query string to API endpoint for filtering:

```
myapi/customers/?first_name__icontains=foo
```

For find customers which has 'foo' in first name **AND** 'bar' in last name:

```
myapi/customers/?first_name__icontains=foo&last_name__icontains=bar
```

I want to find customers which has 'foo' in first name **OR** last name. But I don't know what is the best way to specify OR filter within query string.

An option: I can solve with use `||` in query string and parsing it at server side as below but I don't know this is a preferred method:

```
myapi/customers/?first_name__icontains=foo||last_name__icontains=foo
```

I saw APIs which using query string for filtering results but I did not find any related article with making OR filtering within query string. This approach is wrong? If not;

What is the best way to use OR statement in query string?

Note: django-tastypie using `__icontains` for like search in database, ignore it:

`last_name__icontains=foo` equal to `last_name ilike '%foo%'` in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with tastypie, however, to do or queries in django use Q https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-object.

So wherever in tastypie that allows you to define the returned query do.

```
Customer.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains='foo') | Q(last_name__icontains='bar'))
```

Note: If an object matches both parameters will return this object twice. If this is a concern use .distinct(). However, this is a expensive DB.